# Things we put on the left side of lists

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I'm looking for an umbrella term (hypernym) that covers the things we put on the left side of lists — bullets, numbers, letters, etc. Is there such a word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS specification calls these things "list item markers" ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#propdef-list-style-type)).